# How should i18n language structure be set up in a react native project?

Tags: react-native

I am developing a react native project through expo. I will integrate the i18n language structure.
However, in the examples I looked at, they always processed page by page. How can I set up the structure by managing it from one place?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your localisation data into a JSON file like in the instruction here https://docs.expo.dev/guides/localization/#translating-app-metadata and then use it from any place in your app by identifier. Structure of the JSON file you can find in the documentation for [i18n](https://www.i18next.com/misc/json-format)

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true
      }
    },
    "locales": {
      "ja": "./languages/japanese.json"
    }
  }
}
```